# How to choose bandwidth parameter for RBF

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, radial-basis

I am implementing a logistic regression with RBF (Gaussian) kernel. Here are the steps I tried:

1. first finding centers with k-means
2. perform the transformation using $e^{-(||x-c_i||)^2/2\sigma^2}$
   Currently I am estimating $\sigma$'s by calculating the variances of distances between each cluster center and points in that cluster. This gives poor result compared to standard logistic regression. Then I multiplied the variances with different numbers, and with increasing the multiplier, the accuracy increases upto a certain value of the multiplier. My first question is, why this is happening? Second question, how actually I should estimate the variances?

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply perform hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: @Rakib Together with other parameters in a problem involving kernel, it is  usually estimated with grid search in a cross validation framework. There is a huge literature on that. CV has tons of answers, do a search.

Comment: @horaceT, thanks. But what might be the initial choices of this parameter for CV?

Comment: Here is one way. Soares, C., Brazdil, P. B., & Kuba, P. (2004). A meta-learning method to select the kernel width in support vector regression. Machine learning, 54(3), 195-209.